# Jquery .focus() to clear text retains default text in textarea

Tags: jquery

So I have a .live() click event on a textarea which allows user to leave comments.
I also have this Jquery function to clear the default text of 'Leave a comment...' and unbind the event as so if the user clicks on the textarea again their comment is not erased.

Here is the function.

```
$('#comment-textarea').live('click', function(e) {
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).unbind(e);
});
```

However, when the user submits the commment, the default text is submitted even though it is cleared and they enter their own text. I thought it was the unbind event causing this, but I also wrote it like this.

```
$('#comment-textarea').live('click', function(e) {
        if($(this).text() == 'Leave a comment') {
            $(this).text('');
        }                            
});
```

But it still submits the initial text. Has anyone ran into this before?

***EDIT

So 100% for sure the jquery events are not binding to element that are not within screen view. If I scroll down in the div, anything below the bottom of the div and out of view do nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you should work with `val()`, not `text()`. `<textarea>` is an HTML form control, and for form controls, you use `val()` function to get their current value, or `val(x)` function to set their current value.

```
$('#comment-textarea').live('click', function(e) {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).unbind(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val` rather than `.text`. Also `.one` is a better solution for firing an event once:

```
$('#comment-textarea').one('focus', function(e) {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Also, take a look at the `placeholder` attribute in HTML5 (it achieves the same thing in modern browsers without JS):

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Answer (score 0):

replace all your  `$(this).text('');` with  `$(this).val('');`

Comment: I have tried those, but what I'm noticing now that I look at it again, is that it works for only the first comment box then the rest leave the default text. I'll try the .one Alex suggested see if that helps

Comment: Wrong again, the comments are loaded into a div with a scrollbar. Looks like only the comment box in view is accepting the comment. When I scroll, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [HTML5 `placeholder`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) plus [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr) and [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) to support old browsers and write more **semantic** code.

```
<textarea placeholder="Leave a comment..."></textarea>
```

That's it!